# What does モンスター娘のいる日常 mean?

Tags: particle-の, compounds

I can understand モンスター娘 and 日常, but I can't understand モンスター娘のいる.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いる means " one be there" in this case, so モンスター娘のいる日常 means " ordinaries which the monster girls are there".

This "の" is used instead of "が" which is set behind a subject.

Comment: Does `の` in `お兄さんのばか` serve the same purpose as in `モンスター娘のいる日常`?

Comment: I think they are different.  The の of 雨の降る様子を眺める is the same usage of モンスター娘のいる日常.

Comment: Is there any learning material on this usage of の?

Comment: の have many usages. http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/171157/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AE/

Answer (score -1):

Literally: Everyday life in which monster daughter exists. 
Commonly: Everyday life with monster daughter

Comment: I still don't understand what purpose `の` serves.

Comment: Well, I'm not that good with grammar, but I know that 'no' particle is used to show possession.

Comment: If I regard の as possession, モンスター娘のいる日常 doesn't make sense to me.